# sql syntax error when connecting to MariaDB using python

Tags: python, mariadb

I am getting the below error when running a python script to connect to MariaDB using Cron. But when I run from my local, I don't get this error? why is that? and what is the fix? 
 `my_list` is a list that contains multiple values and I am passing those
 to the `sql` query.

> pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, u"You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1")

```
 cur.execute("select VC_ID,concat(NAME,'/',Item_NAME) from books where VC_ID in %s" % repr(tuple(map(str,my_list))))
```

Comment: Invalid quotes: `’/‘`

Comment: I changed it to double quotes like "/" . but now getting this error - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Use a proper programming editor or IDE, one that doesn't introduce smart quotes.

Comment: @AndyG, I made the change to the quotes but still same error.

Comment: @Mona Are you sure that it is the exact same error? Store the string in a variable and print out its value so that we can see what you are trying to execute.

Comment: @Mona: Don't change it to double quotes (`"`),  use single quotes (`'`).

Comment: And you might need to assign a name to the result of your `concat` function like `... concat(NAME,'/',Item_NAME) as full_name ...`.

Comment: @AndyG, here is the print out - select VC_ID,concat(NAME,'/',Item_NAME) from books where VC_ID in ('cmxns', 'sctdns', 'datns')

Comment: @Matthias, I tried this. still same error. I am not understanding the fact that when I run like this : python myScript.py , it works. But when I do like this in cron: /bin/python myScript.py , it gives me this error.

Comment: Display the query after the value has been bound in.

Comment: @RickJames here is the quere: select VC_ID,concat(NAME,'/',Item_NAME) from books where VC_ID in ('cmxns', 'sctdns', 'datns')

Comment: @Mona - Well, the error message implies that there is an extra `)` at the end of the statement.  But I don't see it.  So, I am stumped.